# signal statement must use <= to assign value to signal

Tags: vhdl, sequential

I've got this error in the expression "individuos(x):=cout" of the following code. What I'm trying to do is assign to each array of individuos a different random "cout" input sequentially. If I change the expression to "individuos <= cout", it'll asign the same "cout" to all "individuos", the same will happen if i trie to build a sequential statement with the assert function. How do I fix this?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

--package genetica_type is
--type genetica is array(0 to 49) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
--type fitness is array(0 to 49) of unsigned (2 downto 0);
--end package genetica_type;


  use work.genetica_type.all;

   entity conexao is
   Port ( 
    clk : in bit;
    cout: in unsigned (7 downto 0);
    individuos: out genetica
     );
    end entity;


   architecture Behavioral of conexao is
   --type genetica is array (0 to 49) of std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
   --signal s_individuos : genetica;

   --signal i: genetica;
   begin



   process (clk)
   begin
   If (clk 'event and clk = '1') then

   for x in 0 to 49 loop

   individuos(x) := cout;
   end loop;



   end if  ;

   end process;

   end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The error message says it all: you have to use the signal assignment `<=` to assign a value to the output port `individuos`. At the moment you are using variable assignment `:=`. To achieve what you intend to do you could use an additional signal or variable which sweeps through all indeces of `genetica`. Each clock cycle this additional signal is used to point to one element in `genetica` and to assign `cout` to it.

Answer (score 2):

> I've got this error in the expression "individuos(x):=cout" of the following code.

That is a syntax error. Use `<=` exactly as the compiler says.

> What I'm trying to do is assign to each array of individuos a different random "cout" input sequentially. If I change the expression to "individuos <= cout", it'll asign the same "cout" to all "individuos"

That is exactly what you ask it to do :

```
  If (clk 'event and clk = '1') then
    for x in 0 to 49 loop
       individuos(x) <= cout;
     end loop;
  end if  ;
```

On every rising clock edge, loop 50x performing 50 assignments, each of the same data, to all 50 addresses.

What I think you want to do, is, on every clock, perform ONE assignment, and increment the address to point to the next location.

```
signal x : natural range 0 to individuos'high;
...

if rising_edge(clk) then
   individuos(x) <= cout;
   x <= x + 1 mod individuos'length;
end if;
```

This code has several other differences from yours:

1. It uses the simpler rising_edge(clk) function
2. It will still work when you change the size of the input array.
3. It still has a bug : if you change the array lower bound to something other than 0, it will fail... for example:
   `type genetica is array(3 to 49) of ...`

Easy to catch this with an assert:

```
Assert individuos'low = 0 report "Array Individuos bound error" severity failure;
```

It also runs continuously. If you want to start and stop it, or reset the address counter, or stop when it reaches 50, that takes additional logic.

Comment: Thanks, I've understood the code and it was able to solve the problem.